# PostgreSQL + PostGIS count with ST_DWithin multiple distance at once

Tags: postgis, postgresql, count, st-dwithin

I am using `ST_DWithin` to count rows that are within 5KM, What I want is count on multiple distance at once with single query i.e count for 5KM, 10KM, 20M

**Current Query**

```
SELECT count(*) AS cnt FROM table_name 
WHERE table_name.published IS TRUE AND
ST_DWithin(ST_Transform(table_name.geo_point, 26986), 
            ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(8.398522, 47.000084), 4326), 26986), 5000)
```

Here, 5000 =  5KM

**What I Want**

```
KM_5     KM_10   KM_20
100       215     300
```

**Created Index**

```
CREATE INDEX properties_geo_point_transform_idx ON 
properties
USING gist (ST_Transform(geo_point, 26986)) WHERE 
geo_point IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: If the query was more complex, you could use a CTE, but you just need to use three subqueries here: `SELECT (...) as cnt_5km, (...) as cnt_10km, (...) as cnt_20km` with the (modified) query above in place of the ellipsis. Note that '5km_cnt' is not a legal SQL name (leading numeric), none of these queries are using indexes, and that  a `geography` cast would eliminate the need to do a `ST_Transform` (which is inaccurate if the geographic points are in WGS84)

Comment: Also, [EPSG:26986](https://epsg.io/26986) is completely inappropriate for 8E,47N

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the counts are supposed to be cumulative, simply use a filtered aggregate:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE ST_DWithin(<geom>::GEOGRAPHY, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(8.398522, 47.000084), 4326)::GEOGRAPHY, 5000)) AS "5km_cnt",
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE ST_DWithin(<geom>::GEOGRAPHY, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(8.398522, 47.000084), 4326)::GEOGRAPHY, 10000)) AS "10km_cnt",
       COUNT(*) AS "20km_cnt"
FROM   <table>
WHERE  <table>.published
  AND  ST_DWithin(<geom>::GEOGRAPHY, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(8.398522, 47.000084), 4326)::GEOGRAPHY, 20000)
;
```

---

Note that I used the cast to `GEOGRAPHY` here; to utilize an index you want to create one on the `CAST`:

```
CREATE INDEX ON <table>
  USING GIST ((<geom>::GEOGRAPHY))
;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer sir, but I have created the index already so do I need to case geography here or using ST_Transform will do the trick? As it is already using my index

Comment: @AlwaysSunny "*Also, [EPSG:26986](https://epsg.io/26986) is completely inappropriate for 8E,47N - Vince*" - you *can* use `ST_Transform`, but you want to be extra careful.

Comment: Your ST_Transform SRID is very incorrect. You should not be using it.  Using a `geography` cast is the correct solution here.

Comment: Okay sir thanks for the reply I will change then.

Comment: I have used this example while using ST_Transform 26896 from here http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html