# Different results for GEOGRAPHY and ST_TRANSFORM query on geo_point field

Tags: postgis, srid, geography, st-dwithin

I am finding properties that are within 20K distance using `ST_DWithin`. But when I try
with `::GEOGRAPHY` casting the result is different from `ST_Transform`. **Note:** SRID of `geo_point` field is 4326

**Indexed Field:**

```
CREATE INDEX properties_geo_point_transform_idx ON properties USING gist (ST_Transform(geo_point, 26986)) WHERE geo_point IS NOT NULL;
```

Using **GEOGRAPHY**,

```
SELECT id,geo_point,ST_AsText(geo_point)
FROM   properties
WHERE  properties.published
  AND  ST_DWithin(geo_point::GEOGRAPHY, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(8.398522, 47.000084), 4326)::GEOGRAPHY, 20000)
ORDER BY id
```

Returns **360** rows

Using **ST_Transform**,

```
SELECT id,geo_point,ST_AsText(geo_point)
FROM   properties
WHERE  properties.published
  AND  ST_DWithin(ST_Transform(geo_point, 26986), ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(8.398522, 47.000084), 4326),26986), 20000)
ORDER BY id
```

Returns **344** rows

When I try to check which points are missing between them using below query,

```
WITH GEOGRAPHY AS

(
SELECT id,geo_point,ST_AsText(geo_point)
FROM   properties
WHERE  properties.published
  AND  ST_DWithin(geo_point::GEOGRAPHY, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(8.398522, 47.000084), 4326)::GEOGRAPHY, 20000)
ORDER BY id
),
ST_TRANSFORM AS
(
SELECT id,geo_point,ST_AsText(geo_point)
FROM   properties
WHERE  properties.published
  AND  ST_DWithin(ST_Transform(geo_point, 26986), ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(8.398522, 47.000084), 4326),26986), 20000)
ORDER BY id
)

SELECT * FROM GEOGRAPHY LEFT OUTER JOIN  ST_TRANSFORM ON GEOGRAPHY.id=ST_TRANSFORM.id 
WHERE ST_TRANSFORM.id IS NULL
```

I found below 16 points are missing on ST_TRANSFORM part.

```
"POINT(8.40028 46.82024)"
"POINT(8.39473 46.82052)"
"POINT(8.39801 46.8207)"
"POINT(8.42244 46.82132)"
"POINT(8.39879 46.82075)"
"POINT(8.40522 46.82061)"
"POINT(8.42434 46.82157)"
"POINT(8.40572 46.82071)"
"POINT(8.40572 46.82071)"
"POINT(8.20105 46.88213)"
"POINT(8.3985206 46.820629)"
"POINT(8.4231175 46.8212294)"
"POINT(8.3948126 46.820464)"
"POINT(8.3954042 46.8205728)"
"POINT(8.4064802 46.8208733)"
"POINT(8.4043592 46.8202558)"
```

So my question is why ST_Transform missed some of the data point ?

Comment: The `GEOGRAPHY` type calculates *spheroidal* distance, i.e. taking the curvature of the earth into account, and is thus highly precise. *Projections* necessarily introduce distortions to any derived metrics. Also, again, the projection you are using [seems to be wrong](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/385895/postgresql-postgis-count-with-st-dwithin-multiple-distance-at-once/385906#comment632151_385906), which results in even higher distortions!

Comment: You are trying to use a Lambert Conformal Conic designed for use over Massachusetts in Switzerland. This demonstrates a fundamental lack of understanding of the purpose of projections. You cannot insist on using a conic projection 6000 kilometers from the area of coverage and complain about accuracy. There exist projections appropriate for use in Europe, but they are unlikely to produce more accurate distances than a geodesic calculation.

Comment: @Vince agreed sir. I've fundamental lack of understanding of the purpose of projections that's why I asked the question here.But some of us here don't like and started down voting it :(

Comment: The GEOGRAPHY type calculates spheroidal distance in the unit "metres" with reasonably good accuracy.